# zookeeper librdkafka example

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

Hello All I am new to kafka and have to work on a project in C.

I have installed the broker and zookeeper from kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz

`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

I have written a C program to be the producer and My consumer which works is from this command.

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic vCPE_Events --from-beginning
```

Till here it is fine.

Now I am trying to get those messages from the rdkafka_zookeeper_example provided by librdkafka library.

However when I connect and run from the localhost the below command I dont see any messages on std out.

```
./rdkafka_zookeeper_example -C -t v_Events -p 1 -k localhost:2181 -A -X debug=all  -Xfetch.message.max.bytes=200 -X log_level=6 -d all
```

I have tried to Produce messages from the same example as well

```
./rdkafka_zookeeper_example -P -t v_Events -p 1 -k localhost:2181
```

Also note that the consumer.sh script does not pick the messages I send from the zookeeper_example as well.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the -Xfetch.message.max.bytes=200 configuration, it might be that the messages are too big and thus wont be received. Also update to latest master, a small issue with the initial broker list has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a topic with default partitions i.e. 1
so, the value for `-p` option both on producer and consumer should be `0`

e.g. if you have created a topic with 10 partitions, then `-p` can have values from 0 to 9